# Telegram Bot sendDocument (php on hosted server)

Tags: php, curl, post, file-upload, telegram-bot

I have a Telegram bot with webhook setted on an third-party hosted server.
I can use any [URL query string](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#making-requests) and they work fine.

Now I'm trying to make my bot [send a text file](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#senddocument). If I've understood correctly I need to make a POST request using `multipart/form-data`, and I'm struggling quite a lot to make it work on the hosting server.

```
$url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot<myToken>/sendDocument?chat_id=$<myId>";
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$post = array( 'document' => '@'.realpath('data.txt'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

//DEBUGGING-------------------------------
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
$buffer = "";
foreach ($info as $key => $value) {
    $buffer .= "$key => $value\n";
}
sendMessage($buffer, $<myId>);
//----------------------------------------

$result = curl_exec($ch);

//DEBUGGING-------------------------------
sendMessage($result, $<myId>);
//----------------------------------------

curl_close($ch);
```

(`sendMessage` is a function that I use for debugging since I can't use `echo` on the webhooked php page).

Obviously I don't receive `data.txt` and the two debug messages are:

```
url => https://api.telegram.org/bot<myToken>/sendDocument?chat_id=$<myId>
content_type => 
http_code => 0
header_size => 0
request_size => 0
filetime => 0
ssl_verify_result => 0
redirect_count => 0
total_time => 0
namelookup_time => 0
connect_time => 0
pretransfer_time => 0
size_upload => 0
size_download => 0
speed_download => 0
speed_upload => 0
download_content_length => -1
upload_content_length => -1
starttransfer_time => 0
redirect_time => 0
redirect_url =>
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: URL host is empty"}
```

I've also unsuccessfully tried to make a [CURLFile](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php)... It seems harder than he needs to, considerig that I can do it very easily [locally on my machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33853502/posting-a-file-via-curl-to-the-telegram-bot-api).

Comment: Don’t try and set the `Content-Type` header yourself, let cURL handle that. (It needs to contain the _boundary_ value used to separate the parts of your multipart request as well, but that is of course missing in the value that you tried to specify.)

Comment: @CBroe Right! I've removed those 3 lines but nothing changed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- No need to set the content headers

[To send a local file](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#senddocument), create a [`new CURLFile()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php), and add that to the CURL request;

```php
<?php

    CONST CHAT_ID = '~~';
    CONST BOT = '~~';

    CONST FILENAME = './data.txt';

    // Create CURL object
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.telegram.org/bot".BOT."/sendDocument?chat_id=" . CHAT_ID);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    // Create CURLFile
    $finfo = finfo_file(finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE), FILENAME);
    $cFile = new CURLFile(FILENAME, $finfo);

    // Add CURLFile to CURL request
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, [
        "document" => $cFile
    ]);

    // Call
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    // Show result and close curl
    var_dump($result);
    curl_close($ch);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I was so close when I tried using `new CURLFile()` but I inserted the `chat_id` in the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` array... One more thing, is `"filename"` required? It works also without it

Comment: Glad it worked! [Looking at the docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#senddocument), there is no filename required! I've removed it from the request!

Comment: If I want to delete the file after the upload, is it safe to do it after `curl_close()` or should I wait for something that tells me the upload is finished?

Comment: Not quite sure, I wont take the risk and delete the file after the upload. If you're really curious, you could ask this in a new question.